# remove the backgroud of the marker from an image shown on a map in OpenStreetMap from WPF C# VS2013

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, google-maps, openstreetmap

I would like to add a marker to a map in OpenStreetMap from C# VS2013.

I am working on WPF. I have designed a function to add marker in map but it cannot be shown.

The marker can be shown on the map but because the image is a square and the marker itself has some white background, which covered the area surrounding the marked location. How to only add the marker itself without having any background covering the surround area on the map ?

Any help would be appreciated.

The code is:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using GMap.NET;
using GMap.NET.WindowsPresentation;
using GMap.NET.MapProviders;
namespace try_gmap_wpf
{
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        myMap.MapProvider = OpenStreetMapProvider.Instance;
        GMap.NET.GMaps.Instance.Mode = AccessMode.ServerOnly;
        myMap.Position = new PointLatLng(42.742826, -77.030212);
        myAddMarker(42.344142, -71.067330, ref myMap);

        myMap.MinZoom = 0;
        myMap.MaxZoom = 10;
        //set zoom
        myMap.Zoom = 5;
        myMap.ShowCenter = true; 
        myMap.CanDragMap = true;
    }

    public void myAddMarker(double latitude, double longitude, ref GMapControl myMap)
    {
            System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
            bitmapImage.BeginInit();
            // this image is a square. It has some background covering areas surrounding the marked location.
            bitmapImage.UriSource = new Uri(@"C:\images\map_marker.png");
            bitmapImage.DecodePixelHeight = 15;
            bitmapImage.DecodePixelWidth = 15;
            bitmapImage.EndInit();
            GMap.NET.PointLatLng point = new GMap.NET.PointLatLng(latitude, longitude);
            GMapMarker marker = new GMapMarker(point);
            System.Windows.Controls.Image image = new System.Windows.Controls.Image();
            image.Source = bitmapImage;
            marker.Shape = image;
            marker.Tag = "cde";
            marker.ZIndex = 10;
            myMap.Markers.Add(marker);
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you edit the marker to make the background transparent?

Comment: I di not see the "marker" class has a method to do that. thanks!